# Git submodule silently fails, exits with code 71

Tags: git, git-submodules

I'm running into an issue where most git commands are (apparently) running fine, but `git submodule` commands all fail. They're also failing silently, printing absolutely nothing, not even an error message. This includes just a plain `git submodule` and even `git submodule help` - both produce absolutely no output. The exit code returned (via `echo $?`) appears to be 71.

It's not an issue with the repository, as other users accessing the same directory can use `git submodule` commands just fine.

I presume it's potentially something with the user environment configuration, but the lack of any error message and the lack of easily findable web search results for the error code make it hard to track down.

Does anyone know the reason for the silent failure, or at least have suggestions on how to increase the verbosity of the error message?